# How to compare two acceleration sensors side-by-side?

Tags: structural-analysis, sensors, vibration, acceleration

I have a single axis analog capacitive acceleration sensor (from PCB Piezotronics) which is very reliable but expensive. Now I need more axis, unfortunately can not afford buying anymore. So I have ordered a cheaper and "versatile" alternative, digital SPI sensor (Murata) which is easier to interface without additional analog to digital converter, also it has 3 axis.

On the datasheet it looks quite promising, but in reality it is not. I have noticed that the result is floating, even when the sensor is not moving.
[image: Digital sensor in silence]
I made a FFT and histogram for both new and older sensor, putting them parallel and measuring, Murata looks strange.
Murata SPI: [image: Digital sensor response]
PCB analog:[image: Analog sensor response]
<s>Murata also measures a bit higher about 0.58Hz, when PCB is 0.55Hz.</s> Edit: It is because the sample rate is not exactly the same.

What do you think, is my approach is correct? How would you compare two sensors?

Datasheet of [Murata SCC2230-E02 sensor - Combined gyroscope and 3-axis accelerometer with digital SPI interface](https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/pdf/datasheet/datasheet_scc2230-e02.ashx?la=en):

Datasheet of PCB sensor: http://www.modalshop.com/filelibrary/3701G3FA3G.pdf

Comment: Just throwing some ideas out...Collect the data from both sensors in as close as the same way as possible. (Sample rate etc). Conduct a test and compare the results of both sensors. Compare variance, correlate the data along the time scale and same y axis scale. What is your ultimate goal? Is it to determine if the cheaper sensor is capable for your project?

Comment: @GisMofx Thanks. Why you think correlation is necessary? Yes, I need a cheaper alternative.